# Show number of warnings/errors at the end of the make process

Tags: c++, c, makefile

If you build your project with Visual Studio at the end of the process, if there are any errors/warnings, the informational message is displayed like (just an idea, I don't have VS here):

```
 Build testproj failed - Errors (1), Warnings (12)
```

Is there any way to do this with `make` tool? It should be shown on the last line, right above the cursor?

Comment: You might try suppressing other output: `make -s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for make to generate such a summary, because it doesn't have this information.  Make invokes your compiler and waits for it to finish.  All output from your compiler goes to the terminal (or file if you've enable redirection) so make does not see it.  Your compiler exits with a single error code number which will be 0 if the compilation succeeded and generated an object file, or some non-0 value if it didn't (but that value has no relationship to the number of errors that occurred, and this doesn't count warnings in any event).  That error code is all make sees of your compilation operation.

If you want a summary like that you'll have to generate it yourself by redirecting the output and then searching through it, parsing the messages, and counting them up.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed this is the case. Thanks!